# Multimatch Search on Multi word query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking to implement a `MultiMatchQuery` that searches a term like "Captain America" where the data is stored as `"firstname": "Captain"` and `"lastname":"America"`.

I currently have:

```cs
 MultiMatchQueryBuilder match = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(
        text.toString(),
        "username",
        "firstname",
        "lastname"
    )
        .type(MatchQueryBuilder.Type.PHRASE_PREFIX)
        .operator(MatchQueryBuilder.Operator.AND);
```

This, however, doesn't return any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You, probably, need a [multi_match with cross_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields), as it fits better with your use case.

Haven't tried the code (it's just blindly written), but it should work or at least show the overall idea:

```cs
 MultiMatchQueryBuilder match = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(
        text.toString(),
        "username",
        "firstname",
        "lastname"
    )
        .type(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.Type.CROSS_FIELDS)
        .operator(MatchQueryBuilder.Operator.AND);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks for the link too. Gave this man a fish while teaching him to fish.